# GMock calls wrong mocked function

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have two pure virtual function:

```
virtual bool IsTypeAllowed(
      const std::string& policy,
      eType type) const = 0;
virtual bool IsSubTypeAllowed(
      const std::string& policy,
      const std::string& request) const = 0;
```

mocked in Mock class, like that:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD2(IsTypeAllowed,
                     bool(const std::string& policy,
                          eType type));
MOCK_CONST_METHOD2(IsSubTypeAllowed,
                     bool(const std::string& policy,
                          const std::string& request));
```

With expect calls:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_policy_handler_,
              IsTypeAllowed(kPolicy, request_type))
      .WillOnce(Return(true));
EXPECT_CALL(mock_policy_handler_,
              IsSubTypeAllowed(kPolicy, request_subtype))
      .WillOnce(Return(false));
```

There 
`kPolicy` is `std::string`

`request_type` is `eType`

`request_subtype` is `std::string`

Then it comes to calling IsTypeAllowed:

```
policy_handler.IsTypeAllowed(kPolicy,request_type)
```

it goes to mock of IsSubTypeAllowed.

I heard that GMock might 'confuse' functions if it has the same name and common signature, which is not really my case,due to different functions names.

Is that a common bug, and is there a solution?

Comment: I never heard about such issue in GMock. Can you please provide [mcve], i.e. how this mock is created, passed to unit under test, used in uut and how are expectations set in test?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen updated, i dont want to put a lot of code, i hope this will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case it was another virtual method in base class of mock class being declared with ifdef, something like that:

```
#ifdef SOME_VARIABLE
    virtual void func() = 0;
#endif
```

Which was causing function offset in vtable, in case 'SOME_VARIABLE' wasn't defined.

So it's nothing to do GMOCK or GTEST.

Comment: And that's a (one of many) reason why NOT to add methods to classes conditionally with #ifdefs this way...